# Como usar table em Banner JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

É possível ao invés de usar uma imagem, usar uma tabela em um Banner Slider? E como desativar a transição automática do Banner?

Comment: É possível? Sim, é possível. Mas tudo depende do slider que você tem. Sem o código que você está usando, é difícil dar uma resposta mais completa. Esse é um slider que funciona com basicamente qualquer coisa http://bxslider.com/

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente @CaioFelipePereira, o problema é que o banner se ajusta ao tamanho do primeiro item, e no caso de outros maiores ele "corta" parte do conteúdo.

Comment: Esse bxslider aparentemente não funciona no Android através do cordova, correto?

Comment: Cara, na teoria, é pra funcionar. Que tipo de erro você está tendo?

Comment: O aplicativo apenas fecha ao tentar passar o item do Banner. No navegador está funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Esquece, não funcionou no emulador, mas funcionou no dispositivo sim, muito obrigado!

Comment: Vou colocar como resposta então!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/). Ele deve funcionar da maneira que você quer!

Answer (score 0):

Usei o http://bxslider.com/, que foi indicado pelo [Caio Felipe Pereira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68327/como-usar-table-em-banner-jquery?noredirect=1#comment139426_68327) e descobri que o tamanho do banner pode ser determinado pelo tamanho do elemento que está dentro dele. Basta usar:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        adaptiveHeight : true
});
```